# Fedora 23: AKMODS - Failed to start Builds and Install new kmods from akmod packages

Tags: linux, fedora-23

A few days ago, I updated my Fedora installation then the battery died and the system shutdown.  When I plugged it back in and booted, I got the above error and I was unable to log into to graphical desktop, as well as a suggestion to take a look at akmods.service.  Doing so resulted in the following...

```
 > systemctl status akmods.service
 akmods.service - Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages
 Loaded: loaded (usr/lib/systemd/system/akmods.service: enabled vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat ...  2m 3s ago
 Process: 1005 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/akmods --from-init (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1005 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 April 02 ... system[1]: Starting Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages...
 April 02 ... akmods[1005]: No akmod packages found, nothing to do. [ OK ]
 April 02 ... systemd[1]: akmods.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
 April 02 ... systemd[1]: Failed to start Builds and install new kmods from akmod packages
 April 02 ... systemd[1]: akmods.service: Unit entered failed state.
 April 02 ... systemd[1]: akmods.service: Failed with 'exit-code'.
```

I have akmods-0.5.4-2.fc23.noarch installed, and I didn't find anything that helped in my google searches yesterday.  Thanks ahead of time for any help.